# IntelliCred 16.2 using Live System

Tags: windows-7, memory, freeze, hardware-failure, sql-server

I am a Data Analyst, and I need your help guys. This is my first question ever on superuser. I will explain quickly how this software works. This is credential software which saves some "information" also it has a function to Map applications using SQL queries. I am working here for 8 months and only a couple of weeks start this problem. While mapping the application screen freezes and program Not Responding it may happen 30-40 times in a day. I talked to software developers, and they said that I am working very fast and that's why it happens. I am clicking "same speed" as I was doing on very fist days... PLEASE maybe someone knows what could be a problem and how it can be solved. I thought RAM might be a problem but it quite enough to run the software (8GB). This is how it looks while Not Responding. The screen stays freeze until shut down the program. Thank you so much for your time; any ideas would be accepted and tested until getting the desired result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5DYR.jpg)

This is an error message. If I press Halt Application the program will shut down. If I press Continue after couple clicks and the screen will be freeze.
......
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLibD.jpg)

Comment: That's proprietary software in an enterprise environment. You should be contacting IntelliCred support directly if your IT department is unable or unwilling to help.

Comment: 3 weeks I am on the line to them and they say to my manager that I am clicking too fast and that's not software issue...

Comment: So tell your manager that this isn’t true and you will not be able to work at full speed. There is *nothing* you can do. This is an enterprise IT issue. Once communicated, it is out of your hands.